# How to put option html parameters in separate parent divs using For Loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

So I want my `option` elements of class `.lev2` & `.lev3` in their own wrapper divs. But instead, they're bundled together in one div because of the jQuery code I'm using. To put simply I want to achieve this result:

```
CLOTHES | CLOTHES1 | ART1
ART     | CLOTHES2 | ART2
```

But as you can see from running my code snippet, `ART1` & `ART2` are situated below `CLOTHES2`, which is not what I want. Because I have dozens of `.lev` elements, I'm trying to shorten my code by keeping them in the `for loop`. Could you help me achieve this result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A refactoring to your code is something you should consider, but to achieve what you want you need to change your for loop to:

`for(i = 2; i < 4; i++) { ... }`

And your selector inside that loop to:

`$(this).find(".lev" + i + "").each(function(ev) { ... }`

Comment: Wooow so it was that simple, and I couldn't even figure that out! Thank you so much - believe me you saved me A DAY. Marking yours as Best Answer, thanks, Thanks!